# Template thesis, font and tableofcontents

Tags: fonts, thesis

I was searching for inspiration about thesis formatting. I came across the following

[Link Thesis](http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/4603/1/main.pdf)

I really like the simplicity here. My questions are:
Which Font is used?
How can I format the table of contens like this?
Is there a template which looks similiar?

Thank you very much.
Greetings.

Comment: It's best to ask a single question. The font is Computer Modern.